# Extend JSONDecoder to allow for models to be serialized differently based on endpoint

Tags: ios, json, swift, decoding, jsondecoder

I have many models that, depending on the endpoint, or serialized differently.  My first attempt had a `init(from decoder: Decoder)` riddled with nested `try catch` blocks.  I thought a better solution would be to extend `JSONDecoder` so that when I initialize one, I can specify which endpoint i am pulling from.  Then in my models `init(from decoder: Decoder)` I could have a `switch` like

```
switch
case endpoint1:
   x = decoder.decode(Int.self, .x)
case endpoint2:
   j = decoder.decode(String.self, .j)
```

The problem I ran into is that the class you have inside the `init` is a `Decoder` not a `JSONDecoder`.  I can't figure out a place that, if I extend `Decoder` and allow myself to specify an endpoint, I could actually specify an endpoint, since `JSONDecoder.decode()` instantiates it's own `Decoder` behind the scenes.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed after having previously used a CocoaPod for JSON Decoding and Encoding that I would actually *need* a way to handle different serializations of the same model, but thankfully `Codable` handles this almost on its own.  Any members that will not appear in every serialization, just mark as optional with `?` and if the Decoder can't find a key for it, it will skip it instead of fail.  Similarly, the encoder will just encode members that are not `nil`.
Example:

```
class Book: Codable {
    var title: String
    var numPages: Int?
    var author: String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case numPages = "number_of_pages"
        case author
    }
}
```

This model will be successfully decoded from JSON Data that has:

1. Title
2. Title and Number of Pages
3. Title and Author
4. Title, Number of Pages, and Author

However, because title is not optional, if the JSON Data doesn't contain a title, it will fail.